# Invoke Function When Item in ComboBox is Selected TornadoFX

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

How would I setup a combo box in tornadofx so that a function is called when an item from its drop-down is selected, and the text of the selected item is passed into that function as an argument.

For instance, if I had an array containing names of cities, and those names are set as the items in the combo box:

```
val cities = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Dallas", "New York", "Sacramento")

combobox<String>
{
    items = cities
    //when item is selected from list perform some function on the name of the city selected
}
```

How could I, for instance, invoke a function when one of the items is clicked that prints the city name to the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `onChange` listener to the `itemProperty` of the `ComboBox`, or you could bind the ComboBox to an external property and listen for changes to that instead. Here is a complete example View with a Form:

```
class MyView : View() {
    val cities = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Dallas", "New York", "Sacramento")
    val selectedCity = SimpleStringProperty()

    override val root = form {
        fieldset {
            field("City") {
                combobox(selectedCity, cities)
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        selectedCity.onChange {
            println("City changed to: $it")
        }
    }
}
```